# Android - <terminated> in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors

After I restated eclipse, and my `Android` app won't run any more.

Here is the error report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=1436, tid=6996
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_45-b18) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

[Full Error Report (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/NwwndZzK)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your bin and gen folders, and try again.
I find sometimes Eclipse gets in an odd state, and often that fixes it for me.

Edit: Although your dump looks like environment issues...